# sql query to search string has special characters using mysql

Tags: mysql, select, replace, where-clause, sql-like

I would like to know how to write sql query for search string that has special characters

I have table `dlist` with columns `postalcode, block and floor` and
want to search like `postalcode #block-floor` pattern

Below is the search string type pattern I use

`380100 #06-764` , `380100 06-764`, `380100 6-764`,
`#06-764 380100` , `06-764 380100`, `6-764 380100`

Below is table and query tried

```
id block floor postalcode
1  6    764     380100
2  90    123     123456
3  2     457     456567
```

```
SELECT * FROM dlist WHERE 
CONCAT(postalcode, ' ',block,'-',floor) LIKE
'%380100 #06-764%';
```

Comment: Your SQL does not look like it's valid at all. Try removing the single quotes surrounding `dlist.floor`, remove the `REPLACE` statement

Comment: `REPLACE` is a function, so it It should be `REPLACE(CONCAT(...), '#', '') LIKE ...`

Comment: But if you remove all the `#`, it will never match a pattern that contains `#`, so I don't understand why you want to use `REPLACE`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for reply, I need to write sql query for the pattern mentioned above, updated the question

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: The wildcards in your `LIKE` pattern mean that you'll match floor `7640`.

Comment: You're not concatenating `#` before `dlist.block`.

Comment: Your input patterns aren't consistent. Sometimes you have `#block-floor` first, sometimes it's last. You need to write a parser to figure out what is what.

Comment: It would be better to parse it into separate variables, then use `WHERE postalcode = ? AND block = ? and floor = ?`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for reply, I want to write query when i search different ways ` `380100 #06-764` , `380100 06-764`, `380100 6-764`,
`#06-764 380100` , `06-764 380100`, `6-764 380100`` and i used like should able get the result if i search if floor or postal code or block alone

Comment: This will not be easy to do just in SQL. parse the search string in your application language.